# How to deal with circular structure in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to consume this /profile endpoint in insomnia but it's throwing this error :
{
"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'MongoClient'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'client' closes the circle"
}

```
  router
  .route('/profile')
  .get(authenticateJWT, async (req, res) => {
    // Connect to the database
    await client.connect();

    // Get the user's profile data from the database
    const userProfile = await client.db('pharmaLink').collection('users').findOne({ _id: req.user.id });

    // Disconnect from the database
    await client.close();

    // Convert the user profile data to JSON without the circular reference
    const jsonUserProfile = flatted.stringify(userProfile);

    // Return the user's profile data as JSON
    return res.status(200).json(jsonUserProfile);
  });
```

```
// authMiddleware.js

import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { stringify } from 'flatted';

dotenv.config();

const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('Authorization');

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized - No token provided' });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden - Invalid token' });
    }

    // Only include necessary information from the user object
    req.user = { _id: user._id, username: user.username };

    next();
  });
};

export { authenticateJWT };
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please add to the question the line that causes the error? is it `const jsonUserProfile = flatted.stringify(userProfile);`. And possibly the structure of the object you try to convert to JSON would help too